# Displaying a Movie List on a Website Using Jinja2 and Bootstrap

Tags: python, html, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to display a list of movies on a website using Jinja2 (a template engine for Python) and Bootstrap (a front-end framework). However, I'm having difficulty getting the movie cards to display correctly.When trying to display the movie cards using Jinja2 and Bootstrap, the cards aren't being displayed as expected. I'm facing difficulties in correctly displaying the background image of the card, as well as ensuring that the movie information is displayed clearly and organized.

```
<!--{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block conteudo %}
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Teste de filmes</h2>
<hr>
<ul class="list-group">
{% for filme in filmes %}
   <li>{{filme.title}}</li>
   <p>{{ filme.overview }}</p>
   <p>Release Date: {{ filme.release_date }}</p>
   <p>Vote Average: {{ filme.vote_average }}</p>
   <p>Vote Count: {{ filme.vote_count }}</p>
   <hr>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock conteudo %}-->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block conteudo %}
    <h2 style="text-align:center;">Lista de Filmes</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        {% for filme in filmes %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500{{filme.backdrop_path}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{filme.title}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{filme.overview}}</p>
                        <hr>
                        <h4>Nota média<span class="badge bg-secondary">{{filme.vote_average}}</span></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if loop.index % 3 == 0 %}
                </div><div class="row">
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Checking if the URL of the movie's background image is correct and accessible.
Ensuring that all Bootstrap classes are being applied correctly.
Verifying that the movies variable is being passed correctly to the template.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[click to see project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rPAV.png)

this more files of the project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>AppPython</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AppPython</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{url_for('principal')}}">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('filmes')}}">Filmes</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('sobre')}}">Sobre</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        {% block conteudo %}
        {% endblock conteudo %}
    </div>
    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

sobre.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block conteudo %}

<h2 style="text-align: center;">Diário do Professor</h2>
<hr>


    {% for registro in registros %}
    <!--    <details>
            <summary>{{registro.aluno}}</summary>
            <p>{{registro.nota}}</p>
        </details>   -->
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_{{ registro.aluno }}" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse_{{ registro.aluno }}">
            {{registro.aluno}}
          </a>
        </p>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse_{{ registro.aluno }}">
          <div class="card card-body">
            {{registro.nota}}
          </div>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
    <form action="{{url_for('sobre')}}" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Aluno</label>
            <input type="text" name="aluno" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome do aluno" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nota</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nota" placeholder="Digite uma nota" required>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
{% endblock conteudo %}
```

idex.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block conteudo %}

<h2 style="text-align: center;">Lista de Frutas</h2>
<hr>
<ul class="list-group"> 
    {% for fruta in frutas %}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{fruta}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    <form action="{{url_for('principal')}}" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exemploFruta">Fruta</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="exemploFruta" type="text" name="fruta" placeholder="Digita uma fruta:">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
</ul>
{% endblock conteudo %}
```

Comment: It would help if you said exactly what the problem was, instead of saying vague things like "the cards aren't being displayed as expected".  What is the **exact** problem?

Comment: I would like this code to capture data from a website's available API so that I can extract display information such as name, image and movie descriptions

https://www.themoviedb.org/

this is the website and I have already done the steps to get a key in order to use it for my project

Comment: You still have not said what the **exact** problem is.  I would imagine your program has several steps -- search the API for the desired data, fetch it from the API search results, then display it.  Which of those steps,  precisely, is the problem?

Comment: the site was supposed to list images and movies locally in an application on my machine. However, I cannot extract the data provided from the API made available by the website mentioned above. The specific problem is the extraction and display of the film's image and title. Did you understand?

Comment: No, I still do not understand, because saying "I cannot extract the data" is not **SPECIFIC**.  What is the actual problem?  Why, exactly, can't you extract it?

Comment: TemplateAssertionError
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: block 'conteudo' defined twice

Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: this is the error that appears on the page locally

Comment: Okay, so it seems that you have `{% block conteudo %}` twice in the template.  Edit the question and add the full template.

Comment: Also, why did we have to talk for 45 minutes before you posted the actual error message?  Why wouldn't you post that at the beginning?

Comment: the code model or the error that is displayed locally?

Comment: No, the html template file.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear from the beginning, I'm just starting to learn this.
I will edit my html template now

Comment: It looks like the first `{% block conteudo %}` is causing the problem, even though it is commented out with `<!-- -->`.  Try actually removing it from the template, instead of commenting it out.

Comment: Well, it displayed it without error, but it still doesn't display the images, titles and synopses of each film

Comment: Okay, so now we're back to my first question -- where, exactly, is the problem?  Is the problem that you're getting the wrong results back from the API, or is the problem in the local display?

Comment: open the image at the end of the question please. She should have a movie list. Example: Kung fu panda 4 with poster and description of the film

Comment: Yes, I see the title "list of films" with nothing underneath, but that could be caused by a hundred different problems.  You need to narrow it down for us.  Are you calling the API correctly?  Are you fetching the results from the API correctly?

Comment: As I said earlier, it seems like your program has three main steps -- make a call to the API to search for the desired films, fetch the results from the API, and display the results.  The problem could be in any of those steps.  Do you know for certain that the first two steps are working correctly?

Comment: check the new codes I entered. They performed the expected function even before this unexpected behavior in film screenings

Comment: I've asked you many times to say what the exact problem is, and you keep refusing to do so.  I'm not going to read over all your code to track down the problem.  That's your job.  Anyway, maybe someone else can help.  Good luck.